# Calling generic method with a type argument known only at execution time

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection

Edit:

Of course my real code doesn't look exactly like this. I tried to write semi-pseudo code to make it more clear of whay I wanted to do.

Looks like it just messed things up instead.

So, what I actually would like to do is this:

```
Method<Interface1>();
Method<Interface2>();
Method<Interface3>();
...
```

Well ... I thought that maybe I could turn it into a loop using reflection. So the question is: How how do I do it. I have *very* shallow knowledge of reflection. So code examples would be great.

The scenario looks like this:

```
public void Method<T>() where T : class
{}
public void AnotherMethod()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var interfaces = from i in assembly.GetTypes()
    where i.Namespace == "MyNamespace.Interface" // only interfaces stored here
    select i;

    foreach(var i in interfaces)
    {
        Method<i>(); // Get compile error here!
    }
```

---

Original post:

Hi!

I'm trying to loop through all interfaces in a namespace and send them as arguments to a generic method like this:

```
public void Method<T>() where T : class
{}
public void AnotherMethod()
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    var interfaces = from i in assembly.GetTypes()
    where i.Namespace == "MyNamespace.Interface" // only interfaces stored here
    select i;

    foreach(var interface in interfaces)
    {
        Method<interface>(); // Get compile error here!
    }
}
```

The error I get is "Type name expected, but local variable name found".
If I try

```
...
    foreach(var interface in interfaces)
    {
        Method<interface.MakeGenericType()>(); // Still get compile error here!
    }
}
```

I get "Cannot apply operator '<' to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'"
Any idea on how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, time for a short but complete program. The basic answer is as before:

- Find the "open" generic method with Type.GetMethod
- Make it generic using MakeGenericMethod
- Invoke it with Invoke

Here's some sample code. Note that I changed the query expression to dot notation - there's no point in using a query expression when you've basically just got a where clause.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Interfaces
{
    interface IFoo {}
    interface IBar {}
    interface IBaz {}
}

public class Test
{
    public static void CallMe<T>()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("typeof(T): {0}", typeof(T));
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("CallMe");

        var types = typeof(Test).Assembly.GetTypes()
                                .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Interfaces");

        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            genericMethod.Invoke(null, null); // No target, no arguments
        }
    }
}
```

**Original answer**

Let's leave aside the obvious problems of calling a variable "interface" to start with.

You have to call it by reflection. The point of generics is to put more type checking at *compile* time. You don't know what the type is at compile-time - therefore you've got to use generics.

Get the generic method, and call MakeGenericMethod on it, then invoke it.

Is your interface type itself actually generic? I ask because you're calling MakeGenericType on it, but not passing in any type arguments... Are you trying to call

```
Method<MyNamespace.Interface<string>>(); // (Or whatever instead of string)
```

or

```
Method<MyNamespace.Interface>();
```

If it's the latter, you only need a call to MakeGenericMethod - not MakeGenericType.

Comment: I would like to stub the generic method, based on the type. But if I Make it using reflection, and then stub the generated one, it understand it won't stub what I want.
My guess is that it's impossible? Or is it?
Stub the generic method for all the types in a list...

Comment: @Stephane: It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do. I suggest you ask a new question with more details.

Comment: Note you may get "Ambiguous matching in method resolution" on `GetMethod()`. This happens when the method you trying to get has some overloads. So you need to specify which one you want by using `GetMethod("Name", new Type[] {arguments})`