# C#: Converting a string that's a classname to a T

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection, fluentscheduler

I have a class in the current assembly called "MyJob"

I want this functionality at runtime:

```
JobManager.AddJob<MyJob>(s => s.ToRunNow()) //I don't know about "MyJob" at designtime, so I can't do this
```

If I do this:

```
var thisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var myJobType = thisAssembly.GetType("MyJob");
JobManager.AddJob<myJobType>(s => s.ToRunNow())
```

I get this error (at designtime):
'myJobType' is a variable but is used like a type

Btw, this is FluentScheduler but I'm hoping for a generic answer...

Comment: What is the definition of `AddJob<T>()`?  Like what parameters does it accept?

Comment: @maccettura: https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler/blob/master/Library/JobFactory.cs

Comment: `JobManager` should have overload of `AddJob` accepting `Type` parameter.

Comment: @Plutonix: not really. See the code OP attached. He knows `.GetType(string)`. What he does not know is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10433007/717732

Comment: @tchelidze: it should, but it does not have it, see the guthub src I provided in other commetn

Comment: Ok, so how do you eventually expect to provide the type if you dont know it?  What exactly would be calling this code?

Comment: @DavidFromPhila: By the way, even if you do what you described using `MakeGenericMethod`, you will have another problem. The delegate `s => s.ToRunNow()` will probably need to be based on T, so you may need to build the delegate dynamically too. However, if you ensure that MyType is always IMyInterface, and that the IMyInterface has ToRunNow method, then the delegate can be based on IMyInterface and can be compiled normally. If you go this way, then why don;t you check out `public static void AddJob(IJob job, Action<Schedule> schedule)` and the IJob interface. That may save you some work.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I thought the lambda would be dependent too, but it [turns out its not](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler/blob/1c3a374d3796c27a93dd53badb0645de9e3fe222/Library/JobManager.cs)

Comment: @maccettura: That's simple. Imagine a config file that says: Jobs:Job1, Job2, Job3, JobDaily, JobWeekly, and all of that are tasks' class names that the administrator wants to run. You dont have to recompile the code every time he wants to change it. But you need to read that as strings and then 'convert' it to class name, and then 'convert' it to runnable job or delegate for the Scheduler library.

Comment: @maccettura: I'm getting tired, so sorry, I'll keep it short: OP said `.AddJob<myJobType>(s => s.ToRunNow())`. That's `Action<T>` and IT IS dependent on T. But it can be T=class, or T=interface, the latter being more handy in this case.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl right, but why use the generic overload for that method when you can implement your own factory that returns an instance and use the overload that takes an instance of `IJob`?  I was just trying to figure out if this was an XY Problem

Comment: I explain how you can dynamically load an add-in here: [C# inherit from a class in a different DLL](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254029/41596) (StackExchange site "Software Engineering").

Comment: @maccettura: `nce and use the overload that takes an instance of IJob` - have you read my comments? thats exactly what I said in the last sentence.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl according to the source code, the only parameter on the generic overload, accepts `Action<Schedule> schedule` as a parameter.  Which is _not_ dependent on `T`.  See Line:306 [here](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler/blob/1c3a374d3796c27a93dd53badb0645de9e3fe222/Library/JobManager.cs)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl my bad, we are having two discussions on two different things haha.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: it is worth noting that your link very loosely relates to the problem, and the only thing relevant to be found there is `Activator.CreateInstance`, which may help him in creating the instance of IJob, but that's relevant only provided that OP follows our advise to use `IJob` overload. If he sticks to generics, your comment is totally missed.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Generics are often misunderstood as being dynamic. They offer diversity, but are strongly typed and therefore not dynamic. Making things strongly typed by using generics and at the same time using Reflection to create the generic type parameter dynamically is contradictory. Therefore I am suggesting another approach using polymorphism and interfaces.

Comment: I'm going to go a different way on this. Instead of having different Jobs (classes implementing IJob), I'm going to have just 1 job class (so it will be known at designtime) and pass in a parameter that defines the job, like this: JobManager.AddJob(new MyJob(3), s => s.ToRunNow());