# Generics method inside of generics method

Tags: c#, generics

I have function like this

```
public static void serialize<T>(T serializeObject){
    //this is the trouble
    SerializableEntity<T> entity = new SerializableEntity<T>(serializeObject);
}
```

How can I make that in using generics inside of generics? How to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

Here the compiler error:

[image: Error image]

Comment: `//this is the trouble` What is the trouble?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling generic method with a type argument known only at execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325156/calling-generic-method-with-a-type-argument-known-only-at-execution-time)

Comment: I got compile error with this code SerializableEntity<T> entity = new SerializableEntity<T>(serializeObject); what's wrong?

Comment: @mrhands: What compiler error? Please, don't make this a puzzle.

Comment: Can you add some code for SerializableEntity?

Comment: Thanks it has been solved now.. I use that from the dll library I get after I checked the code It tells like the answer below..

Comment: @Habib not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong *per-se* with the code you have: that compiles fine:

```
class SerializableEntity<T> {
    public SerializableEntity(T obj) { }
}
static class P {
    public static void serialize<T>(T serializeObject) {
        //this is fine...
        SerializableEntity<T> entity =
            new SerializableEntity<T>(serializeObject);
    }
    static void Main() { /*...*/ }
}
```

So the real question is: *what does the compiler say*? The most obvious one would be if it says something like:

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '`SerializableEntity<T>`'

which is a "constraint" violation; if that is what you are seeing you need to add the constraints to `serialize<T>` to prove to the compiler that the constraints are always satisfied. For example, if `SerializableEntity<T>` is declared as:

```
class SerializableEntity<T> where T : class
{...}
```

then you simply transfer that constraint to the method:

```
public static void serialize<T>(T serializeObject) where T : class
{...}
```

Note that other constraints are possible, including:

- `: class`
- `: struct`
- `: SomeBaseType`
- `: ISomeInterface`
- `: new()`

Comment: @mrhands advice for next time: include the exact compiler error message (ideally copied as text) in the question. Or even better: copy the error message into *google* first, and see what the internet says...

Answer (score 1):

You probably have different constraints on T in the method and in the class.

Take in mind that if the class says:

```
where T  : class, IDisposable
```

Then the method has to have at least the same *where*