# C# Any function as parameter

Tags: c#

Is it possible to created a method that takes ANY method (regardless of it's parameters) as a parameter? The method would also have a `params` parameter which then takes all the parameters for the parameter-method.

So basically what I want is something like this:

```
public void CallTheMethod(Action<int> theMethod, params object[] parameters)
```

But then for any method, not just for methods that takes an int.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you could pass the non-specific `Delegate`, but `DynamicInvoke` is *sloooooowwwwww* (relatively speaking)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would this be more useful than calling the method directly? I must say I'm intrigued though

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the point of this? It seems very error prone. Why not just run the method?

Comment: This *may* be what you want:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325156/calling-generic-method-with-a-type-argument-known-only-at-execution-time

Comment: @MarcGravell So it would become public void "CallTheMethodDelegate theMethod, params object[] parameters)"? I know it's slow, but the library I'm using actually asks a string, containing the method name, and a object[], so I thought to make a wrapper so I don't have to manually copy-paste the method names. In case I decide to change the names, so the compiler will tell me if I forgot to change some ^^

Comment: It is possible, but you need a wrapper lambda.

Comment: @TheOddler Take a look at http://monotorrent.blogspot.pt/2009/12/yet-another-inotifypropertychanged-with_05.html, you might be able to use Expressions to do what you're after.

Comment: @RoadieRich Very interesting article. Not what I need for what I'm trying to do now, but still very smart way of doing stuff. Learned something from that :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, with a delegate:

```
public object CallTheMethod(Delegate theMethod, params object[] parameters)
{
    return theMethod.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
}
```

But see [Marc Gravell's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338375/c-sharp-any-function-as-parameter#comment26917601_18338375) on your question :)

> Well, you could pass the non-specific `Delegate`, but `DynamicInvoke` is *sloooooowwwwww* (relatively speaking)

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I get an error: "Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'". What I have is a method "DoSomething(int number);" And then your method. So I tried "CallTheMethod(DoSomething, 5)" and then I get the error... Am I doing something wrong, or is there a catch I don't know about?

Comment: I get the same error. I recommend the answere of @itsnotalie.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible, but not what should be done.

This is what I would do:

```
public void CallTheMethod(Action toCall)
```

You might go "huh". Basically, what it lets the user do is this:

```
CallTheMethod(() => SomeOtherMethod(with, some, other, parameters));
```

However, if you want it to return a type, it involves generics:

```
public void CallTheMethod<T>(Func<T> theMethod)
```

You can put generic constraints on that type, do whatever you want with it, etc.

Comment: Very true, what I'm asking doesn't seem like a good thing to do. Though Unity wants the name of a method when calling an RPC. So I though to write a little wrapper, so I don't have to hard-code the method name.
Could you also take a look at the comment on Matten's answer? You seem to be very knowledgeable about c#. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use DynamicInvoke to call the methods:

```
Action<int> method1 = i => { };
Func<bool, string> method2 = b => "Hello";

int arg1 = 3;
bool arg2 = true;
//return type is void, so result = null;
object result = method1.DynamicInvoke(arg1);

//result now becomes "Hello";
result = method2.DynamicInvoke(arg2);
```

A method to do this would become:

```
object InvokeMyMethod(Delegate method, params object[] args)
{
    return method.DynamicInvoke(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Delegate` and `DynamicInvoke` to do this, although just like what other people said, it's slow.

If you get error **Cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'**, you may need to cast it when passing the function as argument. For example if you have:

```
public static void registerMethod(Delegate method, params object[] parameters) {
    var ret = method.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
    // ...
}

public static long myAdditionMethod(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

then you can call the function like this:

```
registerMethod((Func<int, int, long>)myAdditionMethod, 1, 2)
```

Or you can also use `Action<>` instead of `Func<>` if the method's return type is `void`.

Note:
The solution above is not always required. Depending on your C# project configuration, you can just simply call `registerMethod(myAdditionMethod, 1, 2)` without getting any compilation error.