# c# Generic Converter for

Tags: c#, wpf, generics

I have a converter that allow me to convert between SelectedItems and a Generic `List<MyType>`

```
public class SelectedTiposDocsToList : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var Selecteditems = value as IList;
        List<MyType> MyTypeList = Selecteditems.Cast<MyType>().ToList();
        return MyTypeList;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now this is a common task for me and want to extend this class to allow a generic type is this something like this maybe ?

```
public class SelectedTiposDocsToList : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert<T>(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var Selecteditems = value as IList;
        List<T> MyTypeList = Selecteditems.Cast<T>().ToList();
        return MyTypeList;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Is this Possible ?
If Yes.. How to use thsi type of converter on XAML ?

Comment: I'm going to say no, since you wouldn't be implementing the interface anymore. An interesting question though! Could you pass the type on the parameter variable instead?

Comment: Maybe. But really don't have much experience on this. And don't know how to pass more parameters to the converte just using XAML sintax.

Comment: I agree with Bradley.  However, you could make the converter call a service that uses generics.  Nothing prevents that.  Pass the class in the converter's parameter...

Comment: @GayotFow. Maybe some sample to see how ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez, there's a wonderful answer from the legendary Skeet  with 97 up votes on how to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325156/calling-generic-method-with-a-type-argument-known-only-at-execution-time

Answer (score 4):

No, this would not be a valid implementation of IValueConverter. However, you can pass a type on the parameter:

```
{Binding MyVariable, Converter={StaticResource SelectedTiposDocsToList}, ConverterParameter={x:Type local:MyType}}
```

Then you would use `Select` with the `Convert.ChangeType` method: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var Selecteditems = value as IList;
    var MyTypeList = Selecteditems.Cast<object>().Select((i) => System.Convert.ChangeType(i, parameter as Type)).ToList();
    return MyTypeList;
}
```

Verified as compiling on VS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a bit of reflection: [`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) to get the type, [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wcxyzt4d) to invoke the [right constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx), and [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod) to give the parameter to [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

```
public Type ConvertType { get; set; }
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(ConvertType);
    var methodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Cast");
    var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(ConvertType);
    var convertTypeList = Activator.CreateInstance(type,
                    genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { value }));
    return convertTypeList;
}
```

You can specify the type in XAML with [x:Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx).

```
<myns:SelectedTiposDocsToList x:Key="Conv" ConvertType="{x:Type myns:MyType}" />
```