# Calling generic ambiguous method using string with qualified name of a class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, .net-4.5.2

Assuming that I have a third party class Foo with a signature like this:

```
void Execute<T>();
void Execute(string[] args);
```

Instead of calling

```
Execute<Bar>();
```

I need to use the qualified name of the Bar classe to invoke the generic method. 
Example:

```
Type barType = Type.GetType("Program.Bar");
Execute<barType>();
```

I've already tried some answers I found on other threads but all of them gave me issues. For instance, I can't use the GetMethod("Execute") since it throws an ambiguous excpetion.

Comment: It sounds like you want to dynamically invoke the generic method based on a `Type`. If so, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325156/calling-generic-method-with-a-type-argument-known-only-at-execution-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it like this:

```
class A 
{
    public void Execute<T>() { }
    public void Execute(string[] args) { }
}

var method = typeof(A).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(
    m => m.Name == "Execute" 
    && !m.GetParameters().Any()
    && m.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 1
    );

Type barType = Type.GetType("Program.Bar");

method.MakeGenericMethod(barType).Invoke();
```

You can either change `FirstOrDefault` to `First`, or add some error handling if `null` is expected (depends on your use case).

Comment: Any reason not to use `Type.GetMethod(string, Type[])` instead of enumerating all methods?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yep - because we want to find a method with exactly one generic argument (If for example, there was a `void Execute() { }` overload)

Answer (score 0):

Type parameters have to be known at compile time, so in order to call the method directly, you will need to either wrap the type or change the signature to take in a type.

Otherwise, you will need to use reflection to invoke the method by name.