# How can I cast a Class<T> to something that acts like a Class<T extends Foo> at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, dynamic, reflection, casting

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
class FooClassAnalyser<T extends Foo> extends ClassAnalyser<T>
```

(where `ClassAnalyser` is an abstract base class for a number of concrete implementations; and `FooClassAnalyser` is a concrete implementation that's specialised for the case in which `T` extends `Foo`). It has a constructor that looks like this:

```
FooClassAnalyser(Class<T> classToAnalyse)
```

In another class, I have a static factory method for `ClassAnalyser`s that calls an appropriate constructor depending on the type of `classToAnalyse`:

```
static <U> ClassAnalyser<U> constructClassAnalyser(Class<U> classToAnalyse)
```

The functionality I want is to check to see if `U instanceof Foo`, then construct a `FooClassAnalyser` and return it if it is.

However, I can't find a way to fit this within Java's type system. Type erasure means that we can't do anything clever with `U` directly. However, the fact that we pass `classToAnalyse` in as an argument makes it possible to test to see if `U instanceof Foo` via using reflection:

```
if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(classToAnalyse))
```

My problem is that unlike `instanceof`, this "instanceof via reflection" isn't visible to Java's type system. In particular, passing `classToAnalyse` directly as an argument to `FooClassAnalyser`'s constructor fails with a type mismatch because Java doesn't know that `classToAnalyse` is actually a `Class<U extends Foo>`.

The best solution I've found so far is to use an unchecked cast to make `classToAnalyse` a `Class<? extends Foo>` (it is *actually* checked, but Java's unaware that it's checked). That at least makes it possible to pass it as an argument to `new FooClassAnalyser`, and get a `FooClassAnalyser<?>` object in return. The problem, however, is that this doesn't then convert back into a `ClassAnalyser<U>`, because Java doesn't recognise that casting `classToAnalyse` to have a different generic bound nonetheless doesn't change the fact that the `Class` object is still the same object (and thus is still a `Class<U>`); in other words, all Java can see is a `FooClassAnalyser<?>` that it doesn't recognise is also a `FooClassAnalyser<U>`, and thus converting back requires another unchecked cast. The result is code that compiles and runs, but with numerous warnings about type safety.

Most of the other things I've attempted have been syntax errors (e.g. a variable of type `Class<U extends Foo>` can't be declared directly; Java doesn't parse that properly). It should be noted that I don't actually have an object of type `U` at any point; I'm attempting to analyse the class itself, and thus only have `Class<U>` objects to work with.

Is it possible to write code like this in a type-safe way?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think you can do any better than what you're doing already (with unchecked casts). It always gets gnarly when you do _anything_ slightly more advanced with Java generics.

Comment: As a side note, you don't have to use an unchecked cast to `Class<? extends Foo>`. You can use [`clazz.asSubclass(Foo.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: @Radiodef: yes, but `clazz.asSubclass(Foo.class)` returns a `Class<? extends Foo>` which has lost the knowledge about `<U>`. You can use it to construct a `FooClassAnalyser<? extends Foo>` safely without warnings, but have no clean way of returning it as `ClassAnalyser<U>`…

Comment: @Holger Yeah, that's why it's a side note.

Comment: This is an older question, so I am not sure if this is a solved issue or not, but shouldn't the reflection package have a method for calling the method or constructor you need by passing in the reflected generic type? I know c# can do this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/325161/1026459), which is why I asked.

Comment: @TravisJ: I don't need to call a method or constructor at all, just to cast an object. I've been using the solution of "two unchecked casts" for a while; but it's ugly, I asked this question hoping that there was a better one that actually respected Java's type system, but it seems like there isn't. As a side note, calling `Method<T>()` in Java, with `T` not a compile-time constant, is very easy due to type erasure; you just call `Method()` (with no angle brackets) and get a compile-time warning, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that unlike `instanceof`, this "instanceof via reflection" isn't visible to Java's type system. In particular, passing `classToAnalyse` directly as an argument to `FooClassAnalyser`'s constructor fails with a type mismatch because Java doesn't know that `classToAnalyse` is actually a `Class<U extends Foo>`.

This will happen as long as you're passing a `Class<U>` to `constructClassAnalyser`.  You didn't provide us with much code, so I can't write an explicit solution for you; however, it would be a lot more simple if you can find a way to pass `U` to `constructClassAnalyser` instead of `Class<U>`.

`static <U> ClassAnalyser<U> constructClassAnalyser(U objectToAnalyse)`

To check its class, you can use `objectToAnalyse#getClass`; you can also use `instanceof` to verify that `U extends Foo` if `objectToAnalyse instanceof Foo` returns `true`, and then cast it to its respective class if required.

Comment: The whole point of a `ClassAnalyser` is that it analyses a class; it doesn't necessarily have an object of that class available. So this solution won't work, and this doesn't really answer the question. (Even if we did have an object of the class available, though, I'm not convinced that you could get rid of the second unchecked cast in my current solution, although it'd be fairly easy to see how you could get rid of the first.)

Comment: If you have the class, just make a new instance of it using `Class#newInstance`

Comment: That requires the class to have an accessible constructor, and also requires appropriate arguments to be found for the constructor. Additionally, the constructor might have side effects. (I still don't see how it would solve the initial problem, though.)

Comment: So make one!  You're only using it to check the type anyway

Comment: (This conversation should really be taken to chat, but I don't have enough reputation yet.) As far as I can tell, you're suggesting fixing a type inference issue via creating a new no-argument constructor for every class we might potentially need to analyse (which automatically limits the method to only analysing classes that we *can* edit, and which could logically have a no-argument constructor; how would you initialize `final` fields that aren't meant to be nullable?). That seems very inefficient, as well as not being general enough to solve the original problem.